# where is forceScheme function y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I want to work in https app I cant geerate https links whit "url" blade function
in some ask question say have use this, but, not works

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Answer (score 0):

after read manual found...

Use the function **secure_url()** from laravel 5.2 and new versions

```
$url = secure_url('user/profile');

{{ secure_url('your-link') }} //instead url()
```

reference [laravel secure_url() function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-secure-url)

Answer (score -1):

in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
}
```

update your AppServiceProvider accordingly and every url will be forced to https

Comment: where is defined? not where put that